# Elasticsearch multiple fields autosuggestion

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I want to implement autosuggestion functionality using elastic search. I can use nGram filters to match partial words on multiple fields and its working fine as expected. Output of the search returns full document with multiple fields as required. Now my problem is, how do I give autosuggestion to the user based on the matching field. e.g. I have got 5 fields:

```
{userId:'rakesh',firstName:'Rakesh','lastName':'Goyal','mobileNo':'123-123-1234','alternativeMobileNo':'123-123-1235'}
{userId:'goyal',firstName:'Goyal','lastName':'Rakshit','mobileNo':'123-123-1236','alternativeMobileNo':'123-123-1237'}
```

In the above example if user types 123, I want to return 123-123-1234, 123-123-1235, 123-123-1236, 123-123-1237 (4 auto suggestions).

Similarly if user types Rak, I want to return Rakesh, Rakshit (2 auto suggestions).

How do I know match exists in mobileNo and alternativeMobileNo field for first example and return results accordingly?

How do I know match exists in firstName and lastName field for second example and return results accordingly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**How do I give autosuggestion to the user based on the matching field?**

When user types **123**, store it in a Java variable, prepare a query like below inserting that variable into and send a request to ElasticSearch.

```
{
    "query" : { 
          "query_string" : {
              "query" : "*123*"
           } 
     }
}
```

The above query will manage to check it in both fields `mobileNo` and `alternativeMobileNo`.

Similarly, if user types **Rak**, the query will be similar to the previous one,

```
{
    "query" : { 
          "query_string" : {
              "query" : "*Rak*"
           } 
     }
}
```

And I think you want to use [highlighter api](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) to answer your last **how** questions, which allows to highlight search results on one or more fields.

A screenshot of highlight example in es :

[image: ES Highlight api]

Comment: Sorry for the late acceptance as I was working on some other things..works perfectly!

Comment: Is there any way to eliminate the duplicate results in highlight ? e.g. If I search for rak*, we might have rakesh twice in the highlight response but we are supposed to show it only once..